# wordpress access widgets or plugins outside of admin and with php

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to access plugins outside of the admin panel? Meaning rather than putting them in the sidebar and "activating" in the admin panel can't we just call the script with an include file? I think this is  possible but how do we know how to activate it? For example:

```
 <?php
include('wordpress/wp-content/plugins/blog-post-calendar-widget/wp-calendar.php');
?>
```

This links to a calendar that should display my posts. It does not. But WordPress is working so I declared it correctly but its just not getting the calendar this way.

Below is the file I am including. The question is **WHAT FUNCTION DO I CALL TO INIT THE CALENDAR?**

Here is a link to the file I am including so you can see the php: [CLICK HERE](http://massmediamail.com/exampleCalendar.php)

Answer (score 1):

my guess would be the `widget` function which looks like it takes args and an instance from Wordpress, so you would have to populate those variables with the right information for your Wordpress (title etc). It also looks like you need to call `WP_Cal_Active` either before or after the widgit function.